# SQL - Retrieving latest message for a CASE WHEN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I have a problem here trying to get one of my `CASE WHEN` statement to query each row for something called `is_op` as it's returning the same number for all rows. Here is the code:

```
SELECT `mid`, `message`, `created_at`, 
CASE WHEN (SELECT `uid` FROM `bulletin_message` WHERE `bid` = 1 ORDER BY `mid` ASC LIMIT 1) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `is_op`, 
CASE WHEN `bulletin_message`.`uid` = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `is_me` 
FROM`bulletin_message`
WHERE `bid` = 1 
GROUP BY `mid` 
ORDER BY `mid` ASC
```

As you can see I'm trying to select messages with the condition `bid` must equal to 1 and `uid` must equal to 5. While `is_me` returns the correct value for each row, `is_op` isn't reflecting the correct value for all the rows at all. It displays `1` at the result of the statement, rather than showing if a user is an OP or not based on the oldest value of `mid` or `created_at`. I don't think I am correctly querying each row like `is_me` statement.

This is all the data of the table:

```
mid = message uid; bid = bulletin/thread uid; uid = user uid

|   mid  |   bid  |  uid   | message | created_at |
---------------------------------------------------
|      3 |    1   |      5 |   ...   |      ...   |
|      5 |    1   |      6 |   ...   |      ...   |
|      6 |    2   |      7 |   ...   |      ...   |
|      9 |    1   |      5 |   ...   |      ...   |
|     10 |    1   |      7 |   ...   |      ...   |
|     11 |    1   |      6 |   ...   |      ...   |
```

What can be done to improve this line of code so that it can query each row? Thank you!

Edit: OP is Original Poster, sorry for not clarifying that! It's usually the person who post the first in each `bid`.

Comment: What is your desired output?  What constitutes an "OP" ?

Comment: What is is_op column logic? what does it suppose to check, because you are always comparing the same value so the results will always be the same

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying! OP is Original Poster and I usually query for the oldest `mid` or `created_at` to get the OP. However, in this query where I'm supposed to find if the user (uid 5) is the OP or not. I understand I am comparing the same result. I was hoping there is a solution for this as I can't see what else could be improved on the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your subquery is based on a fixed predicate, ``bid`= 1`, so it is bound to return the same value *for all rows*.

Something like this would make more sense:

```
SELECT `mid`, `message`, `created_at`, 
        CASE WHEN (SELECT `uid` 
                   FROM `bulletin_message` AS t2 
                   WHERE t1.`bid` = t2.`bid` 
                   ORDER BY `mid` ASC LIMIT 1) = t1.`uid`  
               THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END AS `is_op`            
FROM`bulletin_message` AS t1
ORDER BY `mid` ASC
```

The subquery is correlated using `bid` field: it returns the OP of the current thread.

Comment: Ah thanks, it made a lot of sense! I've forgotten about the wonders of aliases for this purpose. I'll always remember this. Thank you very much!